# HTML Range Slider - Decimal max/min values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few range sliders I am working with for Height and Weight Metrics. The issue is when I am working with feet and inches I want them both on the same slider. I.e. 1.01 - 1.12

At the moment I am set up like with a max value of 10 and a min value of 0 and a step of 0.01.

However, I want a max decimal value of 12 as there are only 12 inches in a foot. Once that hits 12 then the value of the units should increase by 1 as if it got up to 0.99.

I've been scouring the internet and cannot find any way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Use integer inches, but change the display to feet'inches (as `6'02`)  (note you've said 1.12 which would not be valid, also don't use `.` as it's used for a decimal, use the "feet" symbol `'`)